# Are all real-closed subfields of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ conjugate?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, fields

Let $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ be the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$. The absolute galois group $G_\mathbb{Q}$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ acts on the set of real-closed subfields of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$.

> Does it act transitively?

The real-closed subfields are in bijection with the involutions of $G_\mathbb{Q}$ under the Galois correspondence, so another way to ask the question would be,

> Do the involutions of $G_{\mathbb{Q}}$ form a single conjugacy class?

I am asking out of curiosity. I have been unable to locate the answer in any of my texts on real fields, or via internet search, but please forgive me if it is well known. Because the order on a real-closed field is unique, and $\mathbb{Q}$ is order-dense in its real closure, the real-closed subfields $K$ of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ have trivial automorphism group, and it follows that the stabilizer of each $K$ for the action of $G_\mathbb{Q}$ is just the involution fixing $K$ pointwise; thus the action is almost free, and this made me curious if it is transitive.

Comment: $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb Q}/\mathbb Q)$ is probably beyond apprehension on its own, but we know a lot of its quotients.  If this is false, maybe there's some easy quotient that witnesses its falsity?

Comment: For example, $\mathrm S_5$ is a Galois group over $\mathbb Q$ (right?), and its involutions don't form a single conjugacy class.

Comment: Yes I think you're right! Or, $C_2\times C_2\times C_2$ is a Galois group over $\mathbb{Q}$. Wow, that was easy. Please feel free to make this an answer.

Comment: Oh, wait.  An involution in a quotient of $G_{\mathbb Q}$ doesn't obviously lift to an involution in $G_{\mathbb Q}$, so maybe it's subtler than that.

Comment: Again, you are right....

Comment: This answer by Matt E on math.SE says that all involutions in the absolute Galois group are conjugate: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/622935/448

Comment: Hurrah for sufficient weasel words that I wasn't technically wrong.  :-)

Comment: I think Matt E is saying that all the involutions are "complex conjugations" i.e. they are involutions fixing a real-closed field, but I don't believe he is asserting that they are conjugate in $G_\mathbb{Q}$...

Comment: The question he is answering is "Is it true that any element of order 2 in G is conjugate to σ?" But I agree that his answer is not unambiguous on this point.

Comment: I don't see that the argument he gives would lead one to conclude they are all conjugate. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Perhaps the argument goes like this: pick any real-closed subfield of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$. Order-complete it to embed it as a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$. The embedding extends to an embedding of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ in $\mathbb{C}$ by a choice of $\sqrt{-1}\mapsto \pm i$. Since all embeddings of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ in $\mathbb{C}$ have the same image, this means we can automorph $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ in such a way that any given real-closed subfield is the intersection with $\mathbb{R}$. Does that work?

Comment: This fact is mentioned - with some references - at page 5 of [this notes](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/artinschreier.pdf) by Keith Conrad.

Comment: Specifically to @JarekKuben's reference, if (like me) you can't read German fluently but can read French, then you can find a stronger form of this result as Exercise 32 on p. A VI.42 of [Bourbaki - Algèbre](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-34499-5_3).  (Don't ask me about the page numbering.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Any real-closed subfield $R\subseteq\overline{\mathbb Q}$ is a real closure of $\mathbb Q$ (being real closed and algebraic over $\mathbb Q$). Thus, by uniqueness of real closures, any two such fields are isomorphic, and an isomorphism of $R$ to $R'$ extends to an isomorphism of $R(i)=\overline{\mathbb Q}$ to $R'(i)=\overline{\mathbb Q}$, i.e., an automorphism of $\overline{\mathbb Q}$.

Comment: That's it! The argument I gave above in comments is essentially this, only muddied up by the embeddings in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: The key property of base field $\mathbf Q$ is that $\mathbf Q$ has just one ordering.  If we use a number field $K$ in place of $\mathbf Q$ and ask about conjugacy classes of involutions in ${\rm Gal}(\overline{K}/K)$, those are in bijection with the orderings on $K$ (equivalently, they are bijection with the embeddings of $K$ into $\mathbf R$), so ${\rm Gal}(\overline{K}/K)$  has involutions and they are all conjugate if and only if $K$ has exactly one real embedding.